# I got stuck using protocols with associated type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to be able to pass any view model that conforms to the protocol.
The following code works. however, I don't understand why, I thought that using the angle bracket syntax in protocol definition is invalid and I still have to use "any" and bare the performance impact!!

```
import SwiftUI

struct CashItemModel {
    let id: UUID
    let amount: Double
}

protocol ItemListVM<ItemType> {
    associatedtype ItemType
    
    var dict: [String: [ItemType]] { get }
    
}

class CashListVM: ItemListVM {
    var dict: [String : [CashItemModel]] = [:]
    
}

struct CashItemListView: View {
    let viewModel: any ItemListVM<CashItemModel>
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.dict.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
            Text("\(viewModel.dict[key]?.first?.amount ?? 0.0)")
        }
    }
}

var x = CashItemListView(viewModel: CashListVM())
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking but using angle brackets (a primary associated type) is valid since swift 5.7

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question..I was going to rephrase it but the answer below gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem stuck; this works. It works because, as Joakim noted, Swift now has [primary associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0346-light-weight-same-type-syntax.md). You still need `any` because you're storing an existential. If you don't want to store an existential, make CashItemListView generic to move this to the type:

```
struct CashItemListView<VM: ItemListVM<CashItemModel>>: View {
    let viewModel: VM
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.dict.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
            Text("\(viewModel.dict[key]?.first?.amount ?? 0.0)")
        }
    }
}
```